# Ubuntu prompts me for a username and password when i didn't make one for Ubuntu

Tags: windows, password, live-cd, username

When I burned Ubuntu to a disc and tried it without installing it prompts me for a username and password when I didn't make one for Ubuntu. Do I keep them blank or do I use my Windows username and password?

Comment: In no case you will have to use your Windows credentials! Could you post a screenshot or copy the exact words to your question? ([edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/603112/edit) it instead of posting a comment or answer! You can upload the screenshot without registration to http://imgur.com/ and copy the link to your question while you still have too few reputation to post it directly)

Comment: When ever i use my windows credentials its says invalid username and password plus im using the newest version of ubuntu

Comment: Read my comment above!

Comment: @Gryyxn Try using `ubuntu` & `ubuntu` for the username and password respectively.

Comment: @RPI Awesomeness i tried that and it said invalid username/password

Answer (score 0):

Change the password in recovery shell and set up the auto-login for lightdm greeter (aka login screen)

1) When you boot, go to "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and select recovery mode.

[image: Grub - Advanced options for Ubuntu]

2) Once you see the menu below, select root shell, execute the following command `mount -o rw,remount /`.   Next, change your password with `passwd username`, where username is your actual username. You will be prompted to enter new password.

[image: Recovery Menu - root shell selected]

3)  Next execute the command `nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` to edit the configuration file for the login screen (lightdm greeter). You will need two lines, `[Seat Defaults]`  and `autologin-user=username` where username is your actual username. Refer to the image below.

[image: Edit lightdm.conf]

4) All done! Reboot

Comment: Also, refer to [How to recover lost administrative password](http://askubuntu.com/a/24024/295286)